# Find out order of two permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, data-structure

Consider we have two different permutations of the numbers in this set: $\{1,2,...,n\}$

In each question we can ask about the order of two numbers in each of these permutations, for example if we ask for the order of $1,3$ in $(1,3,2)$ and $(3,2,1)$ we get the answer (lower,higher) respectively, which means that 1 comes before 3 in the first permutation and after 3 in the second.

Prove that the minimum order of questions that we have to ask and find out the order of both two permutations is $O(n\log(n))$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I don't see why it has to be $n\log n$? Why not iterate through the permutation looking for either $1$ or $3$, and when you encounter either, that's the one that is lower? That should be linear time in $n$.

Comment: @DonThousand I think the OP means "find both permutations".  So, it's comparison-based sorting, and it's $O(n\log{n})$.

Comment: @saulspatz I'm not sure I understand. What does "find both permutations" mean?

Comment: @DonThousand In the example given, the answer would be $1,3,2$ and $3,2,1$.

Comment: Ahhh, I now understand.

Comment: @DonThousand  In the firs place,we do not know the order of numbers in these two permutations, we want to find out odrer of both permutations by using this type of question explained above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, $O(n\log{n})+O(n\log{n})=O(n\log{n})$, in other words, if you first just ask all the questions to learn the first permutation, and then you just ask all the questions to learn the second permutation, you still get the complexity of $O(n\log{n})$.

Second, to learn a permutation, you (internally, in your head) perform any sort algorithm. For example, if the unknown permutation is $(3,5,1,6,4,2)$ and you want to use "merge sort", you would ask:

- About the order of the first half ($1$, $2$, $3$):

  - Order of $1$ and $2$ ("lower"): $1$ goes before $2$
  - Order of $1$ and $3$ ("higher"): $3$ goes before $1$, so we now know $1$, $2$, $3$ are ordered as $3,1,2$.
- About the order of the second half ($4$, $5$, $6$):

  - Order of $4$ and $5$ ("higher"): $5$ goes before $4$.
  - Order of $5$ and $6$ ("lower"): $6$ goes after $5$ so still need to check with respect to $4$
  - Order of $4$ and $6$ ("higher"): $6$ goes before $4$ so we now know $4$, $5$, $6$ are ordered as $5,6,4$.
- Merging:

  - Order of $3$ and $5$ ("lower"): $3$ is the smallest.
  - Order of $1$ and $5$ ("higher"): $5$ is the next smallest
  - Order of $1$ and $6$ ("lower"): $1$ comes next
  - Order of $2$ and $6$ ("higher"): $6$ comes next
  - Order of $2$ and $4$ ("higher"): $4$ comes next
  - Finally, $2$ is last.

It is well known that sorting algorithms have minimum complexity of $O(n\log{n})$, and merge sort above has that complexity. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm.